# Joomla chronoform - use external php file

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, chronoforms

I'm using Chronoform to manage my forms in my Joomla website, and I'm trying to send my POST datas to an external php file.

For now, chronoform uses form datas to send some emails and then execute a "custom code" to do some php stuff. Maintaining this custom code is really tedious, as I have to go through the admin panel for each modification.

I thought about writing a simple `include` inside my custom code, but is there a cleaner way to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

You can include your custom code into a Custom Code action in the form and maintain it using an FTP enabled editor (I use Sublime Text 3). Please see [this ChronoForms FAQ](https://www.chronoengine.com/faqs/58-cfv4/cfv4-elements-and-html/4376-how-can-i-include-files-or-code-in-a-chronoform.html) for more information.

Depending on what the external PHP file needs you can use the cURL action or write custom code to send the data to it.